# Why is programming in bytecode not as popular or prevalent as programming in assembly?

Tags: assembly, bytecode

You see assembly code and assembly coders all over the internet but there's almost nothing on bytecode. Why is that ? The needs and the advantages of programming in assembly should all hold for programming in bytecode too.

Comment: where there would seem advantages in programming in assembly, there would seem limited advantages in programming in bytecode..

Comment: Thanks Ben. Can you elaborate a little on how the advantages of programming in code are limited ? That is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Because bytecode is a helluva lot harder to type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another reason why bytecode programming is far less popular / common than assembly programming is the genericity of bytecode - its simplicity.

Bytecode instruction sets are largely "ultra-RISC", very simple instructions. Designed for two purposes, to provide the virtual machine with the ability to quickly translate / map into a native instruction set and to allow a high-level compiler to easily create near-native bytecode.

Assembler, on the other hand, also has such simple generic parts - and those are the ones that the bytecode interpreter / just-in-time compiler will actually use to implement bytecode functionality. Few people exclusively use these parts of a native instruction set to write assembler programs. The (Just-in-time-)compiler does that for you.
But assembler has *much more* than that, especially SIMD / vector instructions. These instructions are special-purpose and highly efficient for very particular workloads ("data streaming", in the widest sense - anything that churns through data like dracula through ladies' throats). To this date, there's situations where a bit of human intervention can surpass a compiler result by orders of magnitude. Doing so often requires the use of such vector instructions, in a particular way that the compiler may not be coerced into doing for you.

The price to pay is having to write a native assembly function.

Bytecode lacks these special-purpose instruction extensions, and extending bytecode like that would give away one of the largest advantages of having bytecode in the first place. It would make it unportable between CPU types - the vector extensions of, say, x86/x64 (SSEx), ARM (Neon) or PowerPC (AltiVec) are too different to map a single shim layer on top.

As far as *teaching* assembly-level programming goes, one doesn't need an actual CPU instruction set for that; Donald Knuth in "Art of Computer programming" has used a "virtual" assembler called MIX/MMIX for so long that it predates the existance of the word "bytecode" by a few decades. Concepts that one can teach via x86 assembly language one could also teach via .NET bytecode.

But the main reason (beyond academia, see prev paragraph) why people write assembly language - to exploit platform-specific optimizations made possible by special instruction set extensions - is not a valid reason to write bytecode directly.

Answer (score 5):

Most bytecodes (all of them I've seen, anyway) are designed to be an easy target to compile for. With x86 (for example) you can gain a fair amount with hand written assembly, because it's such a pain to compile for. It's much easier to compile for Java byte codes (for one example) so the gain from writing them by hand tends to be comparatively small.

.NET makes it a bit easier to write programs that generate and use its IL, so it tends to happen a bit more there, though in all honesty most of the examples I've seen looked to me like they were done almost as much because it was there as because it was really necessary.

Comment: Heh, if x86 is hard to compile for, I want to know your opinion about ARM :)

Answer (score 3):

I have doubts about your claims of popularity of programming in assembly, but that's besides the point.

The answer is simply "because there isn't any need to". Artificial assembly languages are designed to service the need of the language for which they are designed, and have a very close relationship with them rather than hardware. There's not much than can be done with them that can't just as easily be achieved in the higher-level language.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how about performance? We use assembly code in C programs, right? Why not, in the same way, use bytecode within Java programs?

Comment: @Syed Fahad Sultan, Only time I've seen in in C programs is to do something C couldn't. (e.g. access certain machine ops.) As I already explained, there is no such situation with Java because the relation between Java and the Java bytecode.

Comment: I think Clojure would argue with you on that one

Comment: @Garet Claborn, Why would Clojure argue that Java Byte Code wasn't designed to service the needs of Java? Or are you saying Clojure would argue that Java Byte Code has a closer relationship to hardware that to Java? Please elaborate???

Comment: @ikegami well more the latter, but not exactly machine ops. Mainly Clojure is written to take advantage of Java Byte Code in a different way than Java. 

Namely, as a Lisp variant, Clojure translates a bit differently when building recursive structures and running recursive algos.References and transactions in Clojure are extended to be more similar to traditional referencing but are still embeddable in standard Java. So IMHO, in that aspect Clojure uses the bytecode to increase performance and memory management, and expose some lower-level features in general.

Comment: ofc using Clojure isn't the same as using bytecode, but the folks maintaining the language are translating to bytecode to achieve these and bypass language barriers. i,e writing Lisp in pure java would be somewhat a nightmare, resource heavy and slow. Lisp and C variants are really the only major languages that are meant to be synonymous with a wide range of assembly instructions AFAIK; I'd put Clojure's cost/benefit comparison to be similar with how Lisp can often beat C in speed and performance at the cost of, generally, maintainability and ease of reading..if you call either readable lol.

Comment: @Garet Claborn, "Mainly Clojure is written to take advantage of Java Byte Code in a different way than Java" does not contradict what I said. (If anything, it supports my point.) I think you misapplied Modus Tolens. Furthermore, I don't see anything in any of your comments that relate to my answer or the original question. I fail to see why you're posting these comments.

Comment: @ikegami I don't see how you think this supports your point. In either case, you've said you've only seen assembly used in C "to do something C couldn't" and "there is no such situation with Java". Clojure uses JVM bytecode to do things which Java can't; pretty simple.

Comment: @ikegami if you would rather something relating to your original opinion to the question; `The answer is simply "because there isn't any need to"` Well this is the case of Clojure and Java, if you need to have a smaller memory footprint than Java can produce, more control over resource management than Java allows or a different method of execution flow than Java allows but still work with the JVM: then you must use JVM bytecode differently. Assembly languages and bytecode almost always have this benefit along with usually producing less commands if written without higher language abstraction.

Comment: @Garet Claborn, "Java byte code being used differently" is not the topic. Like I said, this doesn't relate. I appreciate that you're proud of Clojure, but that doesn't mean it's relevant to all conversations about byte code. I suppose you could tie it in by showing that programmers that use Clojure produce efficient code without having to know anything Java byte code. Or you counter my point by showing that programmers that use Clojure must know or use Java byte code to write efficient Clojure programs. I don't know anything about Clojure, so I don't know if either are true.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason for the popularity of assembly that does not apply to bytecode, is that sometime you *need* to use assembly (e.g: when writing certain CPU-dependant portions of an OS).