# Cross Platform/Architecture Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, architecture, programming-languages, cross-platform, bytecode

I know that assembly language is typically not cross-platform. And even with things like NASM you would still need different code for different architectures and platforms which have different runtimes and implementations of things such as interrupts. But if someone wanted to program in assembly language because they liked it, is there any implementation of a cross-platform cross-architecture assembly language?

**Edit:**

What about not assembly in the traditional sense, but a low-level programming language which looks a lot like assembly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think Donald Knuth's [MMIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX) is what you may be interested in. Knuth writes programs in his [The Art of Computer Programming book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) in this machine/assembly language. To date no CPU supports it directly. There are only emulators. Oh, someone made an FPGA that can run it. But that's about it.

Comment: MMIX is just an ISA with machine code, like RISC-V (which is also open and royalty-free to implement).  It happens to be the one Knuth made up as being good for writing examples in, but it needs to be emulated on CPUs that can't natively execute it.  There are also portable RISC-V and MIPS emulators / IDEs, e.g. [RARS](https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars) / [MARS](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/) for toy programs (with a simplified set of system calls instead of a standard library), or other emulators.  RISC-V is fairly good, a RISC ISA without many weird idiosyncrasies.

Comment: What about programs that take RISC-V code and convert it into actual runnable CPU-dependent assembly code? Does something like that exist? So there is no need of emulating.

Comment: @OsirisTeam RISC-V is already CPU-dependent. Not sure what your question is. Are you asking if RISC-V assembly can be more or less directly translated into assembly for another architecture? Like 8080/8085 asm code could be translated into 8086/8088 asm code?

Comment: Yeah, it would make things a lot easier if there was a single assembly language that can be translated into multiple, different assembly languages that are CPU dependent, by some sort of compiler/translator program.

Comment: @OsirisTeam Easier? For whom or what?

Answer (score 10):

LLVM is a low-level language (whose purpose is a compiler backend) that looks a lot like AT&T assembly, if not 10x worse. Here's an example:

```
define i32 @add_sub(i32 %x, i32 %y, i32 %z) {
entry:
  %tmp = add i32 %x, %y
  %tmp2 = sub i32 %tmp, %z
  ret i32 %tmp2
}
```

This is *roughly* equilavent with the following hand-written x86 assembly:

```
; Body
mov eax, edi
add eax, esi
sub eax, edx
ret
```

LLVM llc 3.3 generates the following code (indented differently for readability):

```
    .file    "add_sub.ll"
    .text
    .globl    add_sub
    .align    16, 0x90
    .type    add_sub,@function
add_sub:                        # @add_sub
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                         # %entry
    lea    EAX, DWORD PTR [RDI + RSI]
    sub    EAX, EDX
    ret
.Ltmp0:
    .size    add_sub, .Ltmp0-add_sub
    .cfi_endproc


    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

The relevant code is this:

```
lea    EAX, DWORD PTR [RDI + RSI]
sub    EAX, EDX
ret
```

As you can see, LLVM has a very powerful optimizer. It is probably the closest that you're going to get.

Answer (score 4):

No. The C language might be what comes closest to a cross-platform lower-level language.

Comment: bytecodes are much closer than C, C is a high level language.  stack based ones in particular (java) and some stack based processors (zpu) are closer to a generic asm.

Comment: bytecodes are not crossarchitecture. They emulate the same processor everwhere. One could as easily say x86 is portable because of QEMU

Comment: The OP asked about programming in a cross-system assembler language. Nobody really writes programs in byte codes.

Comment: @uselpa You can't rule that out. More convincing argument would be, targetting this bytecode from a high level compiler. And that bytecode would have it's own compiler for each architecture.

Answer (score 2):

The following link seems to be relevant.
[Why is programming in bytecode not as popular or prevalent as programming in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925975/why-is-programming-in-bytecode-not-as-popular-or-prevalent-as-programming-in-ass)

Especially ikegami's answer:

> Artificial assembly languages are designed to service the need of the language for which they are designed, and have a very close relationship with them rather than hardware. There's not much than can be done with them that can't just as easily be achieved in the higher-level language.<

Answer (score 1):

As you said, assembly is not cross-platform (you can remove the "typically" part). I don't have much information myself, but looks like [C--](http://www.cminusminus.org/index.html) might interest you as a "portable assembly language" as described in their page.

Comment: And anyway who talked about C here? Look again closer. I said **C--**. Since it seems you didn't even take your time to click the link, I'll quote C-- home page: "You would be much happier with one **portable assembly language**"

Comment: I agree with you, but still your comment is again offtopic.

Comment: I already linked to the main page, go there if you want more details. I'm not going to repeat what's already said. And anyway, this discussion is not constructive for the question itself.

Comment: C-- offtopic? o_O Anyway, I'm off this discussion.

Comment: As you've been already told, bytecode is **NOT** cross-platform. It's not even assembly anyway.

Comment: To avoid this answer being deleted you may want to elaborate on C-- in the body of your answer, as external links can be considered not an answer. (NaA)  Or remove the answer and instead use a comment, under the posters question.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Assembly language generally has a one to one relation ship with the machine code, or instruction set for that processor/system.  Systems are different, by definition, because they have different instruction sets.  So, by definition, you cannot have a cross system instruction set, so no cross system assembly language and have it still be called assembly language.

The closest you will find are virtual instruction sets if you will that are close to machine level in that they have properties that are common to many instruction sets, a one to one or one to few relationship with machine code, but not specific to one machine in particular.  For example java bytecode, python bytecode, pascal p-code, etc.  These are stack based machines, most processors have stacks or can easily implement a stack based machine using loads and stores.  Stack based machines use few registers, another way to get cross system and not make it too painful to implement on the various instruction sets.  Stack based is at the heart of the small-c backend as well which is why it was so easily ported from one system to another.  History repeats itself, these four languages are not the last languages that will boil down to a stack based machine, this will happen again and again.

If you like assembly you may find the java or python backends interesting and perhaps fun.  They probably do not have an assembly language just machine code so you would probably need to write your own assembler.  Personally I would start with a disassembler to get a feel for the language, then go the other way and write bytecode or create an assembler.  Equally fun might be to implement the virtual machine for a particular processor.

Your comments about liking assembly language and then using the word NASM implies x86.  x86 is a somewhat unpleasant assembly language, if you have not experienced others there are a number of more beautiful assembly languages out there.  You should try them instead of looking for one size fits all (which you wont actually find).

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer since you're not answering the question: *"is there any implementation of a cross-platform cross-architecture assembly language?"* And I don't know where you got the idea that he doesn't like assembly...

Comment: I'm not going to repeat what others already said to you. Look at the comments on uselpa's answer.

Comment: if he liked assembly he would enjoy the fact that each has its own language, enjoy the diversity instead of trying to make everything look the same.  searching for a universal assembly language implies the dislike of the varied assembly languages

Comment: I'll look into programming for other programming languages virtual machines. That sounds like a nice idea.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for C. C is too simple: any attempts to build another cross platform assembly language would end up to another C.

Chips are extremely diverse: different numbers of registers, different conventions, different instructions. One chip may get into the door with its left foot first, and other with its right foot first. And take a look at their standards or manuals, both as thick as an Oxford advanced dictionary. One has to abstract all these up to write cross-platform code.